# Increase the size of container relative to inner chart in HTML while using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

My code

### HTML

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="accordion" id="acc3">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#acc3" href="#div3">Inventory Graph</a>
      </div>

      <div id="div3" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div id="inventoryLevels"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
 $('#inventoryLevels').highcharts(chart);
```

If you have used Highcharts, you would know that the chart has two parts: One is the chart itself and the other is the legend, that generally comes below the chart and shows the names corresponding to each 'y-axis' element. My problem is when the number of y-axis components of the chart increase, the size of the inner div being constant, leads to decrease in the size of the chart as the rest of the space is taken up by the legend. How can I toggle CSS/javascript such that the size of the chart remains constant and the legend increases the size of the outer container?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `maxHeight` parameter for the legend, then you will always have the same proportion between chart and legend.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/626kq0bf/